# ApiMember in java client does not include Format

Tags: servicestack

When I use the Eclipse plugin to generate a client it includes ApiMember as seen below.  Problem is that the ApiMember in 'net.servicestack: client' does not include 'Format'.  Is there an option I have overlooked or is this a bug?

```
@ApiMember(DataType="number", Format="decimal", Name="ActionDefCost")
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up resolving this be removing the Format property and relying on the OpenApi plugin to generate the correct property for me.  If I ever find a need to specify Format explicitly then maybe I will have propose adding it to ApiMember in the Java client.

Answer (score 0):

I just saw this, apologies. I've added the new missing properties to [ServiceStack Java libraries](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Java) in [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Java/commit/9cf76357c3cc3dc0b4388577b80c810779ef4d9e).

This change is available from the latest v1.0.35 release of **net.servicestack:android** and **net.servicestack:client** packages.